# check discontinuity of multiple ranges in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to ask you if there's a way by Linq to check discontinuity of multiple ranges, for example we have a class AgeRange:

```
public class AgeRange
{
public int firstValue {get;set;}
public int secondValue {get;set;}
}
```

```
var ageRange1 = new AgeRange(0,2); // interval [0,2]
var ageRange2 = new AgeRange(4,10); // interval [4,10]
var ageRange3 = new AgeRange(11,int.MaxValue); // interval [11,+oo[

var ageRangeList = new List<AgeRange>();
ageRangeList.Add(ageRange1);
ageRangeList.Add(ageRange2);
ageRangeList.Add(ageRange3);
```

in this example we have a **discontinuity between first range and second range**.
is there a way in Linq to check discontinuity between elements in ageRangeList ?
Thanks for you help.

Comment: You need to find all gaps or if any gap just exists? So basically what result do you expect?

Comment: hello, thanks for your interesting, just one, then I return that there's a discontinuity in List.

Comment: What if the ranges overlap?

Comment: `public class AgeRange()` is invalid declaration

Comment: @jira for overlap, it's already managed by an other code, in this step I treat only ranges no overlap

Comment: Could you please define a problem in a more clear way. There can be a lot of ambiguous interpretations. Do intervals [0, 2] and [1, 3] have a discontinuity? Mathematically they probably are but it is unclear from your question. Are intervals [0, 2] and [3, 5] discontinuous. They include integers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and they are continuous in this integer sense so I have to ask. It is probably better to either assert a concrete condition or define it in more mathematical way like for intervals on real numbers

Comment: Also are intervals sorted somehow?

Comment: One more thing: please make your code compile

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `firstValue` always <= `secondValue` (for the same element), you can try to use [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var start = ageRangeList
    .OrderBy(a => a.firstValue).Dump()
    .First();
var result = ageRangeList
    .OrderBy(a => a.firstValue)
    .Aggregate(
        (hasGap: false, s: start.secondValue),
        (tuple, range) =>
        {
            if (tuple.hasGap)
            {
                return tuple;
            }
            else
            {
                var max = Math.Max(tuple.s, tuple.s+1); //hacky overflow protection
                if (max < range.firstValue)
                {
                    return (true, tuple.s);
                }
                else
                {
                    return (false,  Math.Max(tuple.s, range.secondValue));
                }
            }

        })
.hasGap;
```

The downside of such approach is that it still will need to loop through all age ranges.

Comment: Thanks @guru for your suggestion, after adaptation of code, I got this error: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

Comment: @Sacamoto you are trying to convert this to some kind of db query?

Comment: You should have mentioned this in question.

Comment: You should look into mongodb js scripting and/or [map-reduce](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/19/a-simple-mapreduce-with-mongodb-and-c.aspx) capabilities if you don't want to fetch all data to c#.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find first discontinuity and use that information elsewhere

```
public static IEnumerable<AgeRange> FindDiscontinuity(List<AgeRange> ageRangeList) {
        foreach(var ageRange in ageRangeList.Zip(ageRangeList.Skip(1), (a, b) => new {Prev = a, Current = b})) {

            if(ageRange.Prev.SecondValue != ageRange.Current.FirstValue) {
                yield return ageRange.Prev;
                yield return ageRange.Current;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

public static void Main()
{
        var ageRange1 = new AgeRange(0, 2);
        var ageRange2 = new AgeRange(4, 10);
        var ageRange3 = new AgeRange(11, int.MaxValue);

        var ageRangeList = new List<AgeRange>();
        ageRangeList.Add(ageRange1);
        ageRangeList.Add(ageRange2);
        ageRangeList.Add(ageRange3);
        var result = FindDiscontinuity(ageRangeList);

        foreach(var ageRange in result) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", ageRange.FirstValue, ageRange.SecondValue);
        }
}
```

You can change the function so it can return boolean value instead of data.

Comment: Thanks @podlecki for your response, I haved tried your code, I got error in foreach level: The method Zip is not supported in the expression tree: aggregate([]).Where(a